# Restrict Number of downloads by User IP Adrress in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, web, ip

I'm building a PHP webpage which has a Button to download an image. I want to restrict unsigned user to download this image 3 times only.

I don't want to use neither Session nor Cookies because the user can delete his cookies!

I want to use IP, so I used the `$_SERVER` global variable but the problem here is the IP Address is changeable. It's dynamic and change every period of time.

So What should I do?

Comment: I don't believe you can, based upon the restrictions you have placed.  However, depending upon the number of pictures, you may want to put a time restriction on the photograph (that is, stop it from being downloaded more than three times in 24 hours).  It might accomplish the same thing you are looking to do.  Note; this will only work if there are a large number of pictures that users may choose from.

Answer (score 2):

Not all IPs are dynamic, this depends on the ISP. Your problem is identifying the user uniquely, which is impossible to do without requiring users to log in. No matter what you use, IPs, cookies, sessions, client side scripts to do browser fingerprinting or store tokens in the localStorage, a skilled used will always manage to get over your protections.

You can only make it difficult for the users:

- run a client side script to create browser finger print - https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 - and send it to the server to help you identify the user
- generate a server-side token and send it to the client and store it in the localStorage and send it back to the server
- store the IP of the user in the DB
- use session / cookies to add an extra layer of security
- use an hidden iframe to load code from a different domain you own and add extra cookies from there (sometimes users don't delete all the cookies, just those for your site)
- put captchas before the user can download an image so that you're not scrapped by bots

Using a combination of all the above will make it annoying for an user to download pictures from your site without creating an user account, but not impossible.

Comment: But this is not useful for me,the user may remove the cache or download from another browser !

Comment: As I said, there's no way of doing it without asking the user to sign in.

Comment: Really strange! How th other websites do this? I don't know!!

Comment: Anyway I used IP and Cookies together but this is not 100% accurate